# Seo sitemap laravel

Tags: laravel, seo

currently I'm working with seo, I'm creating sitemaps. I'm using laravel 5 with library  `RoumenDamianoff/laravel-sitemap` So I got few questions for you.

1. In my app I have search page, url : `Route::get('/search/result/{category}/{location?}/{pagination?})` . So for example url can be `/search/result/plumber/new_york/page=?1`. How do I define every single option for {category} and {location} variables? Or may search engines understand this definition?
2. I got route : `Route::get('jobs/{pagination?}')` do I have to define every single page with images within? Or can I just write url like this and add all images?
3. What if I got **profile picture** in **search page** and in **user profile**. Do I have to add images to both url's or is one of them enought?
4. Do I have to add routes, with `post` methods too or is it not necessary?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You will probably want to use canonical to tell the search engines to treat these different pages all as the same page and give the href some defaults.

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://yourapp.com/search/result/" />
```

You can read more here: https://moz.com/blog/canonical-url-tag-the-most-important-advancement-in-seo-practices-since-sitemaps